# Steps of migrate symfony 2.8 from localserver to live server

Tags: php, symfony

1. I have installed symfony2 on my localhost.
2. I have uploaded it on my live server. And change the database connection from /app/config/parameters.yml.

> > > But I am not able to access website with direct url (www.example.com) . I am passing "web" folder of symfony inside my url "www.example.com/web" to access homepage. That's wrong way.Can anybody let me know that how can I access my website directly without passing web folder to  my url. Because in cakephp website also link with webroot directory, But open website without passing webroot on website url.

**Regards**

Answer (score 0):

The document root of  your virtual host must be pointing to the web directory. In apache it would be something like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.example.com
  DocumentRoot "symfony/installation/path/web"
  DirectoryIndex index.php
  <Directory "symfony/installation/path/web">
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
RewriteEngine On
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: do you know how to do it on symfony2 via FTP files ?

Comment: It all depends on how your webserver is configured, not how to upload the files. It would help if your describe your remote directory structure and virtual host configuration.